# Using QUARTILE in an Excel pivot table to summarise data by sub-populations

Tags: excel, statistics, excel-2007, pivot-table, data-analysis

I've got a large table of data in an Excel spreadsheet that, essentially, can be considered to be a collection of values for individuals identified as belonging to various subpopulations:

```
  IndivID   SubPopID  Value
     1          A       33.56
     2          E       42.31
     3          D       16.35
     4          A       50.59
     5          F       80.63
     ...
```

There are over 10,000 individuals in this table, and over 50 subpopulations.

I would like to calculate the 5-number summary (Min, Q1, Median, Q3, Max) for each of the subpopulations.

Min and Max are easy in a pivot table.  But Q1, Q2 (median), and Q3 don't seem to be possible.

**Question**

**Is there any way to calculate the quartiles for each subpopulation in a pivot table in Excel?**

The answer should look like this:

```
SubPopID      Min     Q1     Q2        Q3      Max
   A         3.23    12.06   20.35   28.29     50.59
   B 
   C
   ...
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My experience is that you can't do percentiles in a pivot table. I just did a web search and don't see anything to contradict that. I think the best you can do is have your source data in a table so you can refer to it dynamically, and then use the percentile function in another table.

I've seen [one article](http://msbicentral.com/Blogs/JavierGuillen/tabid/134/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/163/Quartile-Percentile-and-Median-in-PowerPivot.aspx) about using PowerPivot, but that's only available in Excel 2010, and it looks hard. I have 2010, and when faced with a similar problem, I still opted to go the route I'm suggesting here.

**EDIT**: Explanation of my proposed alternative:

In answer to your question in the comments, here's how I'd calculate percentiles from a table of data:

[image: Table of percentiles]

It relies on an single formula, which is the same for every cell from F2 to H6. It's an [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx), meaning it's entered with `Ctrl-Shift-Enter`. It uses an IF statement to filter on the various possible SubPopIDs. Here's the formula for F2:

```
=PERCENTILE(IF(Table1[SubPopID]=F$1,Table1[Value],""),$E2/100)
```

Comment: That was my fear.  None of my web searches found anything of value for Excel 2007.  For Excel 2010, however, the `AGGREGATE( )` function looked quite promising, as it has a quartile option built-in.  (Unfortunately, my customer does not use Excel2010 and has no plans to upgrade their organisation imminently).  I'll keep this active for a couple of days, and hope that we're proved wrong and someone has found a clever workaround.

Comment: Doug, could you elaborate on what you mean by "source data in a table and percentile function in another table"?  (Can't see how I could use Excel's 'QUARTILE()' function on a subset of rows, e.g. only on the SubPopID=A in the example).  Thx.

Comment: Please see my edit.  It relies on an array formula with an `IF` Statement.

Comment: Brilliant!  That works perfectly. BTW the screenshots and links were both instrumental in being able to replicate the approach.  Many thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid that this filtered expression doesn't ignore empty values. It will assume a "" as zero which means that the results will be different. Try to find the min value and you will see.

Answer (score 7):

If you need to check a condition for more than one column (a=1 AND b=2) you can expand the array using the * character

```
=PERCENTILE((IF((Table1[SubPopID]=[condition1]) * (Table1[SubPopID2]=[condition2]),Table1[Value]),""),$E2/100)
```

Comment: Hi there.  I think your formula might have a problem -- parentheses seem incorrectly placed.

Comment: yes this should be the code =PERCENTILE(IF((Table1[SubPopID]=[condition1]) * (Table1[SubPopID2]=[condition2]),Table1[Value]),""),$E2/100

Answer (score 1):

I found this [answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/can-i-use-the-quartile-function-in-a-pivot-table/e5c89cfd-43ec-4fed-852a-e80d1c529f23?auth=1) where a solution is described.

It uses the same aproach as described by Doug Glancy but associate it with a calculated field in the pivot table. The answer gives an example excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using ***Measures***:

1. Create a PivotTable and select "Add this data to the Data Model"
   [image: creating a pivot table with data model]
2. In *PivotTabel Fields* right-click on the table and select "Add Measure..."
   [image]
3. Create a Measure using DAX formula: `=PERCENTILE.INC(Table1[Score],0.85)`
   [image]
4. Add the newly created measure to the values of your PivotTable
   [image]
   [image]

Credit goes to [@DougHExcel](https://www.youtube.com/@DougHExcel) for this awesome idea! See his video for a demonstration of this approach: https://youtu.be/dD-oLbOLEBU?si=6FjVqvze8XhcS4rR&t=180