# Referencing data table by criteria

Tags: excel, percentile

I'm trying to use a similar formula as in [Using QUARTILE in an Excel pivot table to summarise data by sub-populations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441090/using-quartile-in-an-excel-pivot-table-to-summarise-data-by-sub-populations) into Excel 2013.

The syntax is: `=MAX(IF(Model[MHH]=10112,Model[Ta],""))`

It is supposed to get the maximum value of all the Ta (outdoor temperatures) at the first hour of the day in january only. The data table is called "Model" and contains the hourly values of three years, with [M] for Month, [HH] for hour. I would like to do the same with the PERCENTILE function, so a DMAX function will not work.

I calculated the Month value and the Hour value together to get a value for the "month-hour" to make it possible to refer to one criterium, a combination of month and hour, in the following format:`1MMHH` to make it possible for the value to be a number.
However if I execute the formula, it returns `#VALUE`.

If I evaluate the formula it give this error at `Model(MHH)`, while if I just use the formula `=MAX(Model(MHH))` it *does* give the maximum of all the values.

Comment: Are  you  entering  this as an array formula,  with  ctrl-shift-enter?

Comment: No. I did now and it works! I didn't know it would be that simple. Thank you very much!