# Excel quartile function with variable array criteria (like countif)

Tags: arrays, excel, variables, quartile

hoping someone can help with my Excel query.

I want to use the quartile function (or similar, could use percentile if that's easier). I have data in a column but I want to limit the data I use from that column.

I have job departments in column A, people's salaries in column B (and other data in the other columns e.g name).

I want to use my one main data list (c. 2,000 rows) to pick out the quartiles for the 10 or so depts I have but I don't want to have to make 10 specific lists to calculate the quartile of each dept.

Is there an option to use a countif or similar function so that I can have a drop down list of my 10 depts and depending on what dept I select my summary table will show the quartiles relevant for just that dept?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by quartile of the department? Is it which quartile the average of the salary of employees in that department. You can reference https://support.office.com/en-US/article/QUARTILE-function-93CF8F62-60CD-4FDB-8A92-8451041E1A2A for a basic understanding of the Quartile function in Excel.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13441090/4996248

Answer (score -2):

Use an array formula =quartile(if(A1:A1000=C2,B1:B1000),.75) press control + shift + enter after entering the formula.  Note: C2 = the department which quartile you are calculating.